# How to parse json file havin dictionary with in dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have json file like this:

```
{
    "url": {
        "188.40.0.138\n": {
            "bytes": 13882,
            "code": 403
        },
        "iantivirus.us\n": {
            "bytes": 13563,
            "code": 503
        },
        "ibmsupport.net\n": {
            "bytes": 13648,
            "code": 503
        },
        "usbnak.com\n": {
            "bytes": 13779,
            "code": 403
        }
    }
}
```

i want to convert this into a csv file with following format:
url,188.40.0.138\n,13882.403

when i uses
(say this is loaded to variable data)

```
for i in data['url']"
    print i['status'] # says index should be integer
    print i # prints 188.40.0.138\n
    print i[0:3] #prints 188.
```

the problem here is i am unable to access inner elements

Comment: Is `'url'` static? Did you mean to write `url,188.40.0.138\n,13882.403`, then `url,iantivirus.us\n, 13563`, etc. or should `url` be omitted? Are there other keys in `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` is just the key; you'd have to look up `data['url'][i]` to get the nested dictionary.

You can nest the loop, using `dict.iteritems()` (Python 2) or `dict.items()` (Python 3):

```
for url, items in data.iteritems():
    for item, value in items.iteritems():
        print url, item, value['bytes']
```

If you plan to write CSV, use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfh:
    writer = csv.writer(outfh)
    for url, items in data.iteritems():
        for item, value in items.iteritems():
            writer.writerow([url, item, value['bytes']])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,k in data.iteritems():
    for y,z in k.iteritems():
        print "url,%s,%s.%s"%(y,z.get('bytes'),z.get('code'))
```